# Cognito Identity Credentials are not authorized to perform action on Kinesis video resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to allow access to a Kinesis video stream using Cognito Identity Pools, but get an `AccessDeniedException` when calling `GetDataEndpoint`.

IAM Role Policy Doc:

```
{
    "Sid": "Stream",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "kinesisvideoarchivedmedia:GetHLSStreamingSessionURL",
        "kinesisvideo:GetDataEndpoint"
        ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesisvideo:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX:stream/<stream-name>/<stream-id>"
}
```

I have tested the policy using the policy simulator, and it shows that the `GetDataEndpoint` action is allowed on the stream, but when testing it in the browser the access denied exception occurs:

> AccessDeniedException:
>   User: arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role//CognitoIdentityCredentials
>   is not authorized to perform: kinesisvideo:GetDataEndpoint on resource:
>   `<resource-name>`

This is how I'm getting the temporary credentials on the site:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
     IdentityPoolId: <identity-pool>,
});

AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        id = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;
        accessKey = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
        secretKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
        token = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
    }
});
```

I've tried using wildcards for the Kinesis video actions and the resource, but still get the same errors. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: hello, did you found a solution that you can share? facing same issue here..

Answer (score 1):

This will be due to the scope down policy that Cognito applies to unauthenticated users. It is further explained here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html

As stated in the above documentation:

> If you need access to something other than these services for your
>   unauthenticated users, you must use the basic authentication flow.

Answer (score 1):

To easily solve this you should also pass the unauthenticated role *RoleArn* to *CognitoIdentityCredentials*.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
     IdentityPoolId: <identity-pool>,
     RoleArn: <unauthorizedRoleArn>
});
```

This will ensure that, as specified [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html),

> If a RoleArn is provided, then this provider gets credentials using the AWS.STS.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity() service operation, after first getting an Open ID token from AWS.CognitoIdentity.getOpenIdToken()

This essentially means that the credentials will be provided using the [Basic (Classic) Flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html)

In addition to this you should also Allow Basic (Classic) Flow in your Identity Pool Authentication flow settings

Comment: You saved my another few hours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I struggled with this for hours and couldn't get it to work even with `RoleArn: <unauthorizedRoleArn>` and following the suggestions in this [issue](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-ios/issues/8).

In my case, my users are already authenticated via **Amplify.Auth.signIn()** but I needed to use **AWS.KinesisVideo()** which isn't included in the amplify sdk.

Ended up using the pre-generated [AWSCrendentials](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/awscredentials.html) post signIn. Might not be the best approach but it does the job.

```
const checkCognitoUserSession = async () => {
  const getAwsCredentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
  const awsCredentials = await Auth.essentialCredentials(getAwsCredentials);

  return awsCredentials;
}; 

 const awsCredentials = await checkCognitoUserSession();

  AWS.config.update({
     credentials: new AWS.Credentials({
        accessKeyId: awsCredentials.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: awsCredentials.secretAccessKey,
        sessionToken: awsCredentials.sessionToken,
     }),
  });

 new AWS.KinesisVideo({ apiVersion: '2017-09-30', region: config.Auth.region });
```